# org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet on select query

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a random issue with this JPA repository on only one customer

this is the repository

```
public interface TestObjectRepository extends CrudRepository<TestObjectPto, Integer>
{
   List<TestObjectPto> findByEndDateAndNameInAndVendorIdIn(Date endDate, List<String> names, List<Integer> vendorIds);
}
```

NOTE : this issue is random if I run the query it will passed, few hours after the same query with same params is failed

this is what I have try :

- in the list of names I'm making sure that the number of characters is less then 4000 but issue persist
- I have also update the oracle jar version on app level to be aligned with oracle instance but issue persist
- I have try to add @Transactional(readOnly = true) on interface level but issue persist again

Any idea what can be the issue ?

main Exception are :

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet


Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P002, instance proddb2.xxxx.net.xxx:xxxxxx (2)
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested
```

full stack

```
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:351)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy150.findByEndDateAndNameInAndVendorMocDefIdIn(Unknown Source)
        ... 124 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:69)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2167)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1930)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1892)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:937)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2672)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1508)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1537)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505)
        at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:135)
        at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:74)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:129)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91)

        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1508)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1537)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505)
        at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:135)
        at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:74)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:129)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
        ... 134 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P002, instance proddb2.xxxx.net.xxx:xxxxxx (2)
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1017)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:215)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:58)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:776)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:897)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1034)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3820)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3867)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1502)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
```

I have enable  query log, below is the SQL query :

```
Hibernate:
    /* select
        generatedAlias0
    from
        MyTestObjectPto as generatedAlias0
    where
        (
            (
                generatedAlias0.endDate=:param0
            )
            and (
                generatedAlias0.name in (
                    :param1
                )
            )
        )
        and (
            generatedAlias0.vendor in (
                :param2
            )
        ) */ select
            mytestobj0_.id as id1_2_,
            mytestobj0_.end_date as end_date2_2_,
            mytestobj0_.import_key as import_key3_2_,
            mytestobj0_.name as name4_2_,
            mytestobj0_.start_date as start_date5_2_,
            mytestobj0_.state as state6_2_,
            mytestobj0_.idf_vendor as idf_vendor7_2_
        from
            mytest_object mytestobj0_
        where
            mytestobj0_.end_date=?
            and (
                mytestobj0_.name in (
                    ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?
                )
            )
            and (
                mytestobj0_.idf_vendor in (
                    ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?
                )
            )
```

Comment: First of all, I prefer to extend from JpaRepository instead of CrudRepository. The JPA one include CrudRepository. Then, a quick search brought me to two sites which offer some additional info to further debug your issue. https://www.tekstream.com/resource-center/ora-12801-error-signaled-in-parallel-server/ and http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01460_unimplemented_or_unreasonable_conversion_requested.htm#:~:text=What%20causes%20the%20ORA%2D01460%20and%20how%20can%20I%20avoid%20it%3F&text=Cause%3A%20The%20requested%20format%20conversion,see%20which%20conversions%20are%20supported.

Comment: Fist you are using *parallel query* which is typically not the case for Hibernate applications. The most probably cause is that one of your source tables has set a parallel `DEGREE` higher than one. (Check in `USER_TABLES` or with your DBA). This should be eliminated but will probably only change the problem. You should log the generated SQL query to see if the problem can be reproduced without Hibernate.

Comment: Thanks @MarmiteBomber for you answer !!!, It is quite likely that parallel DEGREE value can be the issue !, I checked value on customer which problem does not reproduce and the value is 1, and on customer which we have this random issue and the value is 10, so I  update value to 1, and I will monitor the impacted app for few days to confirm